# Action<T> where T is interface

Tags: .net

I haven't found a solution to do something like this.

Say I have an Address class

```
public class Address : IAddress{...}
```

And I have an AddressManager class

```
public class AddressManager{ 
    public void SaveAddress(Address adress)
    {...}
}
```

I later on now have this **SaveAddress()** method information in an MethodInfo object. And can create an Action object out of this information. Like this:

```
Action<Address> action = (Action<Address>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Address>), instance, methodInfo);
```

And then I can execute it like this:

```
action(parameter);
```

That works good, but my problem is that I want the **Address** to be *"generic"* so I can send in anything that implements **IAddress**.

I like to do something like this

```
    Action<IAddress> action = (Action<IAddress>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<IAddress>), instance, methodInfo);
action(parameter);
```

But this gives me a problem since it doesn't match the methodSignature since it excpects an **Address** as parameter.

Or I want to do this (that I don't see to be possible in any way)

```
    Action<parameter.GetType()> action = (Action<parameter.GetType()>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<parameter.GetType()>), instance, methodInfo);
action(parameter);
```

Is there any good way to handle this?

Comment: You can't create a delegate that says "I can take any IAddress implementation" and map that to a method that says "I can only take the Address class and derived classes". Change your method as well.

Comment: It seems obvious, that SaveAddress needs to get an IAddress too, doesn't it.

Comment: The problem is that I decided what method to call depending on what parametertype it has! Then from that parameter I get the methodInfo from a dictonary and then want to call that method but now the problme is that it can be of various types, but they all implement the IAddress interface.